# Error deploying application to Glassfish 3

Tags: eclipse, glassfish-3

When I try to deploy my application named shopping-1 to Glassfish 3 I get the following error:

```
'Publishing to GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3 (Java EE 6)2 at localhost...'has encountered a problen.

cannot Deploy shopping-1
Deployment Error for module: shopping-1: Exception while loading the app :
  java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
```

How do I track down and fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

apparently the `shopping-1.war` file doesn't include the archive containing the `DispatcherServlet` class.

`unzip -l shopping-1.war | grep spring` (on Linux) will give you the list of all spring-related included jar files

Answer (score 0):

1. First run appserver admin-list applications
2. Check  if there are any deployed applications on the server.
3. Undeploy by running  them if there are.
4. Stop the application server.
5. Open the location folder where you have the war file for deployment
6. Check that there is only one war file at a time in it.
   7.Start the application server
7. Deploy the war.
8. Should work fine.